# inserting nodes from another xml file at any place in a document(c#)

Tags: c#, xml

```
XmlTextReader myReader = new XmlTextReader("abc.xml");
XmlDocument mySourceDoc = new XmlDocument();
mySourceDoc.Load(myReader);
myReader.Close();

myReader = new XmlTextReader("pqr.xml");
XmlDocument myDestDoc = new XmlDocument();
myDestDoc.Load(myReader);
myReader.Close();

XmlNode rootDest = myDestDoc["root node"];
XmlElement nodeOrig = (XmlElement)mySourceDoc["root node"].ChildNodes[0];
XmlNode nodeDest = myDestDoc.ImportNode(nodeOrig, true);

try
{
    rootDest.AppendChild(nodeDest);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
}
XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter("pqr.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
myWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

myDestDoc.WriteTo(myWriter);
myWriter.Close();
```

the above code works well if nodes have to be inserted as children of root node.But i want to insert nodes as children of any other node.what should i do?

Comment: Do you *have* to use XmlDocument etc? If you could use LINQ to XML, it would make life simpler.

Comment: i keep on getting the exception--the node to be inserted is from different document context.LINQ to XML hasn't made my life simpler.

Comment: Well it certainly can do... for one thing, you don't need to "import" nodes in LINQ to XML... just adding an existing element to a different document will copy it, IIRC.

Comment: actually,i have to automate creation of an xml file through c#.the file can have any no. of values and different hierarchies depending upon the input given by the user.if user enters---abc#pqr#xyz.output is<abc><pqr>xyz</pqr></abc>.that's why the linq concept is not that useful to me. can you suggest another way?

Comment: And still consider using LINQ to XML, it's a very flexible technique. Besides you could split your input strings and form your xml, with several requests, using LINQ to Objects + LINQ to XML

Comment: @akanki: I don't see in what way you think LINQ to XML wouldn't be useful to you. You do realize that LINQ to XML is an XML API, separate from LINQ to Objects, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say, you have the following xml:

```
<CONFIGURATION>
  <File>D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder1\TestFile.txt</File>
  <Dir>D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder1\</Dir>
  <File>D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder2\TestFile02.txt</File>
  <File>D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder2\TestFile04.txt</File>
  <Dir>D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder2\</Dir>
</CONFIGURATION>
```

And you want to create a new one, containg only *File* nodes; also the root node must be called *Files*. Such xml would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Files>
  <File>D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder1\TestFile.txt</File>
  <File>D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder2\TestFile02.txt</File>
  <File>D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder2\TestFile04.txt</File>
</Files>
```

The following code does this:

```
XElement infile = XElement.Load("In.xml");
XElement outfile = new XElement("Files");
foreach (XElement x in infile.Elements("File"))
    outfile.Add(x);
outfile.Save("Out.xml");
```

This is a simple example, how you can transfer nodes from one xml document to another with LINQ To XML. Consider using this.

You should like it.

**EDIT**

Original xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <abc>
    <pdf>hhh</pdf>
  </abc>
</root>
```

User input:

```
abc#uuu#ttt
```

Output xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <abc>
    <pdf>hhh</pdf>
    <uuu>ttt</uuu>
  </abc>
</root>
```

The code:

```
        string userinput = "abc#uuu#ttt";
        XElement infile = XElement.Load("In.xml");
        XElement temp = infile;
        string[] commands = userinput.Split(new string[] { "#" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        for (int i = 0; i < commands.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i + 1 == commands.Length)
                temp.Value = commands[i];
            else
            {
                if (temp.Element(commands[i]) == null)
                    temp.Add(new XElement(commands[i]));
                temp = temp.Element(commands[i]);
            }
        }
        infile.Save("Out.xml");
```

Comment: i appreciate ur effort but it didn't solve my problem. firstly,the structure of my source file is not uniform,tags can have any random name(as wish of user dynamically). XElement outfile = new XElement("Files");<----this line cant be used.secondly i have to "insert" data i.e. if file has<abc><pdf>hhh</pdf></abc>.and i input abc#uuu#ttt. then the output should be <abc><pdf>hhh</pdf><uuu>ttt</uuu></abc>.Can u help me with that?

Comment: XElement outfile = new XElement("Files"); what is the problem with this line?

Comment: "Files" u mentioned is a tagname. in my case tagname is given by the user on runtime.if i take a string variable and construct a path where i want to insert nodes it doesnt take it.

Comment: i tried this code but it is overriding the old contents---like---- <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <root>   <abc>     <pdf>hhh</pdf>   </abc> </root> user input---abc#uuu#ttt output-----<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <root> <abc>     <uuu>ttt</uuu>   </abc> </root> .i would also like to tell u that i constructed only---<uuu>ttt</uuu> in file in.xml.

Comment: I do not understand you. The code is only an example. It shows you the approach, develop it under your needs.

Comment: Sorry to misunderstand ur code earlier.i reviewed the edited solution and it works fabulously .Thanks.

Comment: Glad to know, it works. Read more about LINQ to XML, you can actually find almost everything in MSDN...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx